# Create diffusion model in Netlogo (Biochemical model: liquids w. living cell)

Tags: netlogo

I am a starter of Netlogo. Now, I need to create a diffusion model in Netlogo for a biochemical model of liquids with living cells. Can you kindly give me some reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. this is purely coding based site. You need to put you coding whatever you have done so far... else we won't be able to give answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Osmotic Pressure model in the Models Library. It's under Chemistry & Physics / (unverified)/

Comment: I guess this one is more relevant!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples in Netlogo Model Library, (File > Model Library > then in search box search diffusion)

For example, this one explores the power behind patch primitive  ‘diffuse’. (Its art related  not chemistery !)

[image]

[image]

Or this one  demonstrates diffusion-limited aggregation.

[image]

[image]